# IBM main frame RACF Users to Active Directory Users

Tags: mainframe, racf

We have a requirement to convert IBM Main frame RACF users to Active directory Users. I am new to mainframe and not sure how the RACF users were stored in IBM Main frame.

We heard from the stake holders we are getting a comma seperated file(.csv) which contains RACF user details. They want to parse the text file/csv file to Active Directory. Does anyone knows how the text file will be output from IBM main frame? I want to know the column name like UserId, Group, Roles or Privileges etc., Please help me on this.

I need the format of the text file outputed by RACF.

This link explains how the text file extracted but the format is not given.
https://wiki.ca.com/display/IMGC10/Prepare+to+Manage+RACF+Data

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: Search-engine for IRRDBU00 and dig around. For instance: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.icha300/format.htm%23format

Comment: IRRDBU00 would have been my first guess as well, but that does not produce comma-separated output. My guess would be that the mainframe-guys will do some transformation of the RACF-data to csv abnd should be able to give you a description of their output.

Comment: Thanks piet/Bill Woodger for your information. 

Piet: Yes. You might be correct. I got the requirement like i will be receiving a text file output from RACF. System should use the output file and push the information to a database.

i found a link where they are exporting a RACF to MDB(Access). 

https://sites.google.com/site/cgcurtis/racfexporttomsaccess